# How to avoid message Container and Input toolbar overlapping in Gifted chat

Tags: react-native-gifted-chat

[image: Chat Screen]

This is my Chat screen, the issue is my message container which shows all message is getting overlapped with my InputToolBar. How to avoid that and have separate two containers which don't overlap each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try prop
`minInputToolbarHeight={60}` // Height as per your need